# How to catch errors from console input

Tags: javascript

e.g. in chrome's developer tools console, when the input throws an error, is there a way to catch it?
i tried window.addEventListener("error",)
but the onerror event listener on window seems not to catch the console stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try (hah) using a [`try ... catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) block. Console errors will be caught automatically by it. This should work in all modern browsers according to Mozilla DN.

```js
function refError() {
  return a; // Intentional for the purpose of example
}

try {
  console.log(refError());
} catch (err) {
  console.log('Caught: ' + err.name);
  console.log('Details: ' + err.message);
  // Do something on error
}
```

Comment: what i meant was actually when you write some code directly in the DevTools/Console UI. and also passively being able to catch it. with out a direct try, catch block.

Comment: Oh, whoops. try ... catch will work in the console UI, but I don't know of a way to catch errors in the dev console without that. If you want I'll delete this answer. I'm tempted to leave it since others might find it useful, though.